# Can $\mathrm{HOD}^{L(\mathbb R)}$ change between models with large cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

It is a celebrated result that if there is a proper class of Woodin cardinals, then the theory $L(\mathbb R)$ cannot be changed by set-sized forcing.

Assume there is a proper class of Woodins. Let $\mathbb P \in V$ and let $G \subseteq \mathbb P$ be generic.  Is possible that $\mathrm{HOD}^{L(\mathbb R^V)} \not= \mathrm{HOD}^{L(\mathbb R^{V[G]})}$?

Comment: Nice question! I think that the answer is negative.

Comment: (By negative answer, I mean of course that HOD doesn't change. Your title and your body ask opposite versions of the same question, after all.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Should i change it then? And do you have a proof?

Comment: It's up to you; and I don't have one, I just think it should be that way based on things I vaguely remember, and probably incorrectly. The key point, according to my faulty memory, is that $L(\Bbb R)^V$ is an elementary submodel of $L(\Bbb R)^{V[G]}$ even when you add each real from $V$ as a named constant. And in that case take the least ranked set of ordinals added to HOD, and use elementarity to argue that all of its elements already satisfy that definition in $L(\Bbb R)^V$. Or something like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila OK I will make the changes.  By elementary submodel do you mean there’s an embedding?  Because if we collapse $\omega_1$, the identity map cannot be elementary.  As I recall, $\omega_1$ is measurable in $\mathrm{HOD}$ under these assumptions, so if it can be a definable cardinal in $\mathrm{HOD}$, then we have a counterexample.

Comment: Wait. Don't you have an expert on $L(\Bbb R)$ in your office?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woodin showed that under $\mathrm{AD}^{L(\mathbb R)}$, $\Theta$ is the least Woodin cardinal in $\mathrm{HOD}^{L(\mathbb R)}$.  See Koellner-Woodin in the Handbook of Set Theory, and Theorem 8.23 in Steel’s chapter of the same book.

Thus if we force to change the value of $\Theta^{L(\mathbb R)}$, by collapsing it to countable, then the new $\mathrm{HOD}^{L(\mathbb R)}$ has a different least Woodin cardinal.

Comment: That's really odd, though. Since the collapse is itself in HOD, and it's homogeneous. So it shouldn't really change HOD, should it? But hey, if Woodin proved it, then he proved it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It’s possible that I’m misquoting things.  But in general I think we can only say that if $\mathbb P$ is homogeneous and OD, then $\mathrm{HOD}^{V^\mathbb P} \subseteq \mathrm{HOD}^V$.  Do you know some conditions that guarantee equality?  (Besides starting from $L$.)

Comment: Hmm. No, I don't think I know of a nice condition. Nevertheless, it would be odd, since you have a forcing, and you have a smaller HOD, but a larger smallest Woodin cardinal.

Comment: @Asaf Here’s a nice example, I’m sure you have seen something similar before.  Start from $L$, add some real $x$.  Then code it into the continuum function on the $\aleph_n$’s, and call this model $M$.  Then $L[x] \subseteq \mathrm{HOD}^M$.  Then collapse everything you did to countable, and call this model $N$.  Then $\mathrm{HOD}^N = L$.  So forcing can erase definitions and remove things from HOD.  Apparently it can remove extenders witnessing Woodinness.  But simply by collapsing, it can also create extenders witnessing Woodiness higher up.  Now that’s weird.

Comment: Stupid resurrection theorem of $\Sigma_2$ properties... Making life confusing...